# Consultas cypress a SQL-server-Management

Tags: sql-server, conexión, testing, cypress

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta de mis pruebas automatizadas de cypress hacia una base de datos en SQL-Management Studio, para cuando se ejecute el bot de cypress este pueda hacer consultas a la base de datos, pero me marca el siguiente error:

> cy.task('sqlServer:execute') failed with the following error:
>
> No connection configuration given

A pesar de ya estar configurado como se sugiere en la documentación.

cypress/plugins/index.js

```
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
  on('task', tasks);
}
```

support/index.js

```
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server';
sqlServer.loadDBCommands();
```

cypress.json

```
"db": {
    "userName": "",
    "password": "",
    "server": "",
    "options": {
        "database": "",
        "encrypt": true,
        "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true
    }
}
```

y la consulta es:
`` cy.sqlServer(`SELECT 'test').should('eq', 'test'); ``

*nota
Estoy usando cypress 9.7.0 y node.js 16.17.0

*Nota #2
La conexión esta hecha con éxito.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías instalar la librería ‘dotenv’, para esto vas al archivo index.js del directorio plugins y aplicaremos los siguientes cambios:

```
    /// <reference types="cypress" />
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
require('dotenv').config()

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
  config.env.baseUrl = process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  return config
}
```

Con eso debería funcionar